# Moqui - How to pick Postgres in "Database Host" in Multi instances mode

Tags: moqui

I am using Moqui 3.0

I am following this guide: https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/framework/Multi-instance+with+Docker

But we want to use Postgres, not My sql. Is there any confirguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for Postgres is similar to MySQL. The way the multi-instance functionality works is with services to perform particular operations for each instance type and database type, and that implement service interfaces that the rest of the multi-instance functionality uses (more general services and the screens and such).

This is not yet in the documentation, but there are services for Postgres similar to the services for MySQL. See the source here:

https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework/blob/master/framework/service/org/moqui/impl/InstanceServices.xml#L791